# Regular Expression to match up to two operators

Tags: regex, swift

I'm building a regex in Swift that needs to check these specific cases:

Match if found:

```
AB*5+4
AB+4*5
AB+4
AB*5
AB
AB+54.45
AB+50.49*54
```

Don't match if found:

```
AB+4+5
AB*4*5
AB*0
```

There can only be zero to two operators (`+` or `*`), but if there are two, they can't be the same. And multiplication by `0` should not match.

The regex I built is the following:

```
[A-Z]{2}(\+|\*)[1-9]{1,}(?:(?(?=\1)(\+|\\*))[1-9]{1,})?
```

The main problem is that I can't predict the conditional in the first captured group, so I can't check something like: if `*` in the first captured group then `+` or vice versa.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What are the rules you're trying to apply? It's not clear from the examples you gave.

Comment: I don't want repeated + or repeated * ex. AB+4+5 or AB*4*5, I can accept only cases like AB+4, AB*5, AB*4+5, AB+5*4...

Comment: What about AB*4+5*7? Can it be only 2 numbers, or are longer strings allowed?

Comment: Only 2 operations max allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`), like this:

```
[A-Z]{2}(\+|\*)\d+(?!\1)((\+|\*)\d+)?
```

As explained in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression), a negative lookahead assertion is

> True if the parenthesized pattern does not match at the current input position. Does not advance the input position.

The regex above matches:

- `[A-Z]{2}` 2 letters
- `(\+|\*)` either `+` or `*`
- `\d+` 1 or more digits
- `(?!\1)` cannot be followed by the same symbol (`+` or `*`) as the first one
- `((\+|\*)\d+)?` optionally, another `+` or `*` followed by one or more digits

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/YKmCpX/2/tests) that passes all the cases you listed as examples and matches your restrictions in the comments.

Comment: Here's [an updated version](https://regex101.com/r/YKmCpX/4/tests); the regex is `[A-Z]{2}(?:(\+|\*)[1-9][\d\.]*(?!\1)((\+|\*)[1-9][\d\.]*)?)?(?!\+|\*)`. The additional rules (allowing just `AB`, allowing `.`s, and excluding `AB*0`) make it a lot more complicated. In the future, please be sure you specify all of the constraints in the question itself. :)

Comment: Sorry Ed, I did a mistake deleting my previous comment, I was trying to better explain was I looking for but wasn't able to edit previous comments so... I messed up.

Comment: I have one last question for you, I elaborated my regex until here: https://regex101.com/r/uzzSBL/2 but what I'm trying to capture for the final phase, is also the group that collects only the names without operations. In the example above I want to collect in another group also (SOCCERCLUB,ZX,FP)..Is it possible without breaking anything?

Comment: @talesfromnowhere I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, but it (1) may not be a job for regular expressions (at least, not entirely) and (2) should be asked in a new question. Anytime you have additional or different requirements from what you put in your question, you should ask a new question to address those. Otherwise, the question and answers end up being moving targets. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Ok, I'll open another question explaining better my goal and linking this one!

Comment: New question is available at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347956/collect-group-with-regular-expression-before-further-matches