# Collect group with Regular Expression before further matches

Tags: regex, swift

This is the final phase of a question started here: [Regular Expression to match up to two operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253769/regular-expression-to-match-up-to-two-operators)

I Have this regex: https://regex101.com/r/uzzSBL/3

The first group collects all the matching strings, regardless from the presence or absence of operators with digits.

**Example of matching group:**

```
Group 1: SOCCERCLUB*9+2,ZX,FP*7+8.90
```

I would like to modify the regex to collect also the strings, WITHOUT operators (if they are present).

**Example of what I want to collect**

```
Group 1: SOCCERCLUB*9+2,ZX,FP*7+8.90   

Group 2: SOCCERCLUB,ZX,FP
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: If you want an actual regex group containing only `SOCCERCLUB,ZX,FP`, then that's impossible. You can't have regex groups that skip over characters in the middle but match stuff on both ends. Why not split the string on the commas, then parse what is left?

Comment: I don't want to skip anything, I just want to collect **also** the regex group without the operators, something like that: (\b[A-Z]{2,12}\b)+, but like that it's collected only the last string inserted (FP in the example). You confirm that it's impossible?

Comment: What you're trying to do is get `{this part}{but not this part}{this part}{but not this part}{this part}`. That's what I mean by "skipping" over some of the string. Doing that with a simple regex match is impossible. You can split the string by the commas, then pull out the parts you want (`SOCCERCLUB`, `ZX`, and `FP`), but you can't get just those parts together in one regex group.

Comment: Perfect, clear. I'll do like you suggest. It's possible to avoid commas on last string? Example: SOCCERCLUB*9+2,ZX,FP*7+8.90**,** In my regex the string inserted will match even if there's a comma at the end of the final string and I don't want that. Negative lookbehind perheaps?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The regex you linked to in your question does not match the string `SOCCERCLUB*9+2,ZX,FP*7+8.90**,**`. I think you mean it shouldn't match, for example, `SOCCERCLUB*9+2,ZX,FP*7+8.90,`. In that case, the easiest thing is just to put at the very end, right before the `$` (or right after; it doesn't matter), a negative lookbehind: `(?<!,)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use a regex to clear a string, and then make match.

```
let txt = "SOCCERCLUB*9+2,ZX,FP*7+8.90"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\*|\\d|\\+|\\.", options: .allowCommentsAndWhitespace)
let newString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: txt, options: .withoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, txt.characters.count), withTemplate: "")

print(newString) // SOCCERCLUB,ZX,FP
```